# Python parsing out nested

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using the simple_salesforce library for importing data from Salesforce. 2 rows come back as what looks like a triple nested dict..

```
OrderedDict([(u'totalSize', 2), (u'done', True), (u'records',

[OrderedDict([(u'attributes', 

OrderedDict([(u'type', u'Account'), (u'url',
u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/98234fd')])), (u'Name',
u'Adidas'), (u'Client_ID', u'100')]), 

OrderedDict([(u'attributes', OrderedDict([(u'type', u'Account'),
(u'url', u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/43243sd')])),
(u'Name', u'Nike'), (u'Client_ID', u'101')])

])

])
```

I tried `queryResults.items()[2].items()[1]` but it looks like you can't nest the ordered dict calls.

How do I get a 2 dimensional (nested) list that would return the 'Name' and 'Client_ID' columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I got your answer right this should do the trick:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict([(u'totalSize', 2), (u'done', True), (u'records', [
    OrderedDict([(u'attributes', 
        OrderedDict([(u'type', u'Account'), (u'url',
        u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/98234fd')])), (u'Name',
        u'Adidas'), (u'Client_ID', u'100')]), 

        OrderedDict([(u'attributes', OrderedDict([(u'type', u'Account'),
        (u'url', u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/43243sd')])),
        (u'Name', u'Nike'), (u'Client_ID', u'101')])
    ])
])

data = [(e["Name"], e["Client_ID"]) for e in d["records"]]

print(data)
```

`[("Adidas", "100"), ("Nike", "101")]`

Comment: What's the purpose of the JSON bit?

Comment: @glibdud Old code I forgot to delete. The `d = json.loads(json.dumps(d))` will get rid of all the nested OrderedDict's making it easier to debug.

Comment: Thank you. Time tested your answer vs the other one. It actually performs faster

Answer (score 1):

```
queryResults.items()[2][1]
```

That gives you a list of `OrderedDict`'s with the attributes. Thus:

```
data = []
for i in queryResults.items()[2][1]:
    name = i['Name']
    clientID = i['Client_ID']
    data.append([name,clientID])

for i in data:
    print(i[0] + " " + i[1]) # This shows you what is is data.
```

Comment: Trying this suggestion

Comment: Thank you, this answer works as well. Cleaner code as compared to the chosen answer however it is a tad slower.

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that my solution isn't nearly as robust to changing schemas as the above answer. You definitely picked the winner :)